# Flutter Scrollbar with scrollController doesn't work

Tags: flutter, scroll, controller, scrollbar

when I wrap Scrollbar() on ListView()
Scrollbar() doesn't work
Can see it but can't drag it

here is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('products', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)),
          elevation: 0.5,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kMediumGap),
              controller: _scrollController, // ✅
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _products.length + 1,

...

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent && !_fetching) {
        debugPrint(' end of list = end of list');
        fetchProducts();
      }
}
```

1. if i remove(detached) the _scrollController in the ListView()
   Scrollbar() works fine. but i can't notice the end of scroll so it's necessary
2. if i set Scrollbar() controller property with _scrollController
   scroll was pretty dirty. not smooth at all.

Is there any reason or solution about it?
I wanna notice end of scrolling and Scrollbar() drag function. both.

Comment: try using `physics`  with `BouncingScrollPhysics or ClampingScrollPhysics ` in the listview you can find in this link also remove scrollbar and scrollcontroller and if you have long data try lazy loading or pagination for better performance  https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-listview-and-scrollphysics-a-detailed-look-7f0912df2754

Comment: I think it's not what I expect but

Comment: that bouncing scroll physics is I've looking for
I saw video tutorial few months ago but i couldn't find exactly skill name  but now you guide it to me, 
thanks 

Comment: happy to help manh

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code it works fine for me. I think there is a problem with your fetchProducts() function.

Comment: well.. actually i didn't fetch when I test it 
i think I should check my the other code more detail thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that replacing `Scrollbar` with `CupertinoScrollbar` did the trick and it's also possible to attach `ScrollController` to it.

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: CupertinoScrollbar(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kMediumGap),
              controller: _scrollController, // ✅
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _products.length + 1,
```